Eye landmark model in Tensorflow not tracking with unseen data
I've been using the UTKFace dataset to create a model that will plot the points around eyes in an image. The training set I'm using is about 40000 images in size and contains augmented images in both scale, rotation and translation. It works well with the training and validation sets. But when I test it with a new augmented image from the set it doesn't work. I've tried slightly tweaking some params and training time but I haven't seen a good change in result.
My layers currently look like this:


inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(200, 200, 1))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5))(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

# Linear layers.
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.1))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=24)(x)




This is a sample output from the validation set after training. This is the result I want.

This is an image from the validation set. This is also correct.

This is the same image but slightly augmented but the eyes haven't tracked.

I'd appreciated any thoughts on what I might do to improve my results.
EDIT : Since posting I've managed to improve the results by increasing the kernel_size and making use of dataset generators per epoch.

(a) What does your inference code look like? Please post it as well. (b) "This is the same image but slightly augmented but the eyes haven't tracked. " -> What augmentation did you apply here?

The augmentation applied is a downwards translation of about 15px, note the white space at the top of the image.
Since posting I've managed to improve the results by increasing the kernel_size and making use of dataset generators per epoch.

(a) Please add that information as part of the question (b) Show your inference code (c) Show both training and validation loss curves (or explain the colours from your loss curve). Please add these details to the question by editing it.
